# PrimeFaces. validateDoubleRange from Bean

Tags: validation, primefaces

I tried the following way ......

```
public class ProductBean {
    public double LOWER_RATE;
    public double UPPER_RATE;
}

<p:inputText id="myRate" value="#{productBean.DEFAULTVALUE}" validatorMessage="Value entered is not between the specified range">
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="#{productBean.LOWER_RATE}" maximum="#{productBean.UPPER_RATE}"/>
</p:inputText>
<p:watermark for="myRate" value="#{productBean.LOWER_RATE} : #{productBean.UPPER_RATE}" />
```

Watermark shows a valid range of 1:20. Even if the entered value is between 1 and 20, I am getting the error: 'Value entered is not between the specified range'

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the requirement could not be met using validateDoubleRange , I moved my validation to the server side keeping the logic in rowEditListener of the dataTable.